# What is the point of NonNull annotation?

Tags: java, android

I don't get how the NonNull annotation is supposed to help. So, let's say I have this:

```
void noNullArg(@NonNull Object o)
{
    // stuff
}
```

If I do this, I receive a warning about how 'o' might be null.

```
void foo()
{
    Object o = null;
    noNullArg(o);
}
```

But if I do this instead, I receive no warning at all.

```
void sendNull()
{
    // Pass null and violate the annotation
    foo(null);
}

void foo(Object o)
{
    noNullArg(o);
}
```

That's a pretty trivial case that is not detected. To top it all off, the compiler seems to think that checking for null if @NonNull is set is unnecessary, when it's obviously not (it says the condition is always false).

Comment: Java compiler will not check call stack .. it will only check immediate caller

Comment: Your 'pretty trivial case' requires either a runtime check or full-blown flow analysis by the compiler. It isn't trivial at all.

Comment: Sure it is. Object o is not checked for null before passing to noNullArg, so it could be a warning. They chose not to do that, but if I check for null inside noNullArg Lint informs me that is a waste of time.

Answer (score 5):

As you might know **Null Pointer Exception** is very common failure case of Java. when compile see  code as second case it will show warning.

Due to the inherent complexity, flow analysis is best performed in small chunks. analyze one method at a time will make good performance and this advantage is that analyze will fast and compiler can warn you as you type.but the dark side is that analysis can't see which values are running between method(as parameter or return). That is the reason in third case it will not show any warning. As **EJP** says it will check runtime.

**@NonNull** means null is not a legal value.

Here the null annotation comes to important. By defining @NonNull annotation you can tell to the compiler that you don't want a null value in position.

but It's the caller's responsibility to never pass a null value, which is to be ensured, e.g., by an explicit null check.

Comment: Right, that all makes sense. So then why does Lint give me warnings if I try to check for null? It says the expression is always false, implying there is no way it can ever be null (which is not true of course). I am disable that I'm sure, but why the patently false warning?

Comment: That doesn't answer my last question at all.

Comment: There is no runtime checking performed for @ NonNull. I just tried it and the method executes as normal even with null for a @ NonNull argument. So if it performs no runtime checking, why does Lint tell me I don't need to bother checking for null myself inside the function? There's no actual guarantee. I see a lot of value in the annotation for notifying anyone that might use the method, so they know what to expect.

Comment: I'd also like to know the answer this question.

Comment: I think that by marking method argument with NonNull, you commit that your method does not support null value for specified argument, so it does not make any sense to add any null check. If you want to handle null values, and make method 'null friendly', simply remove NonNull

Comment: As a general rule I check for nulls when updating old existing code with annotations and leave the null checks out for new code. All extra checks drastically increase the number of unit tests required for proper test coverage.